# How many spells does a Wizard start off with?

Tags: spells, character-creation, wizard, adnd-2e

I'm creating a Mage in AD&D 2e for fun, and want to know how many spells my character starts off with at first level.

I know that there is **Table 21: Wizard Spell Progression**, but my Dad and I can't seem to figure out whether it refers to how many spells I have, or how many spell slots I get per level.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## The *Dungeon Master's Guide* covers starting wizard spells

To determine what spells are in beginning wizard's spellbook, see the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (1989) on Initial Wizard Spells, p. 41 (pp. 60-61 in the revised 1995 edition).

In short, the DM picks a method to use, but a new wizard's spellbook usually contains *detect magic*, *read magic*, and about 4 other spells *either* that the player picks and the DM approves *or* that the DM picks.

The *Player's Handbook* Table 21: Wizard Spell Progression (p. 43) has no impact on what spells are actually *in* a wizard's spellbook. That table shows only how many spells the wizard can memorize and cast of an appropriate level each day.